# Display <video> fallback message for unsupported file formats?

Tags: javascript, html, video, file-format

I am using video element on my page in the following way:

```
      <video src="some source" controls>
        Error message
      </video>
```

To my understanding "Error message" will only display if browser doesn't support `<video>` element. I wanted to see if there is a way to show it or at least replicate this behaviour also if browse doesn't support video format provided in src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via JavaScript as you can use the [`canPlayType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to check if the browser can play the video file format.

For example:

```
var v = document.createElement('video');
// canPlayType returns maybe, probably, or an empty string.
if (v.canPlayType('video/mp4') === '') {
   // boo the browser cannot play an MP4 file
}
```